# fadeout works, but fadein doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, fadein, fadeout

As the title states, I have a function that causes a div to `fadeOut`

```
 $("#myVid").bind("ended", function() {
            //other functions
            $(".control").animate( {
                marginTop: "+=128px"}, 500 );
            $(".control").fadeOut(0);
        });
```

and the one where it fades in

```
$("#myVid").bind("playing", function() {
            //other functions
        $(".control").fadeIn(0);
        });
```

why isn't it coming back in? the video is actually an array, so that's why it fade out on ended and back in on playing... can I get some help here?

should this be possible:

```
$(".control").fadeOut(0).delay(500).fadeIn(0);
```

because `delay()`s always give me tons of trouble, and now is just delaying the whole ended function(if in front) or doesn't go first(if in back)

Comment: Can you please fix your code tags, I can't stand reading them like that. Pretty hard to read actually

Comment: @Jake i fixed them as you posted that. Not sure what happened, sorry

Comment: Is the animation that you do before the fade out pushing the control to a spot where you can't see it when it fades in? (Does the fade _in_ work if you remove the animate from just before the fade _out_?) Regarding your last point, `$(".control").fadeOut(0).delay(500).fadeIn(0)` should work fine.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah, it is, I guess I should be using `hide`. I'm using `fade` because when I started messing around with them I had durations. As to the second part, its pushing the control to a spot where you can see it

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment to remove the bit about `hide()` because I figured that was the reason (also, `hide()` with no params bypasses the animation queue).

Comment: @nnnnnn okay. Actually, your comment about where it pushes the element helped, and I got it, so thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use two functions for when i'm using fades:

```
function fadeIn(id){
    $('#'+id).fadeIn('fade', function() {
    });
}
function fadeOut(id){
    $('#'+id).fadeOut('fade', function() {
    });
}
```

So you could work with those

Comment: Those empty callbacks seem a little redundant, indeed the whole thing seems a little redundant unless you _really_ want to save five characters of typing every time you need to fade, but more importantly how does this help with the OP's problem?